# Limiting regression accuracy

Tags: regression, lstm, function

I am currently using a LSTM Network to solve a regressional problem. The goal is to predict the payload mass using various time series as input data. For our intents and purposes estimating the mass to about 5% of the target mass is completely sufficient.

However I am not exactly sure how to communicate this to the network. The issue I have with this is that, the network overfits and performs very well (much better than neccessary) on various samples and extremely poorly on other samples. I would like to therefore "limit" the accuracy of the regression, with the hope that this will reduce overfitting and also reduce the spikes in the predicted values.

My approach so far is to change the loss function, in a way that when the mean squared error lies under the 5% value for this sample the error is just 0. However I am not sure if this approach actually works as intended ...

Is my thought process correct here or is there any other manner of communicating my wishes to the NN? I have not found much on this topic through google, but I am sure that others must have come across it before me as well. Does a specific name exist to refer to this process of reaching the "early goal".

I am grateful for any input.

Comment: The analogy with higher-order polynomials giving Runge's Phenomenon is to reduce the polynomial order, might reducing the number of nodes in the neural network have a similar effect in this case?